# Apex Charts Rendering with vertical lines

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2, apexcharts

I'm currently using Vue2 and want to implement apex charts into the existing codebase. Everything works really well, but i'm having an issue rendering the chart without the weird vertical lines.

[Apex Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeEjK.png)

Not quite sure what the issue is here

Here's What I tried so far:

```
<script>

export default {
  components: {
    apexchart: VueApexCharts
  },
  props: {
    data: Object
  },
  data() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          id: "chart1",
          toolbar: {
            show: false,
            tools: {
              reset: true
            }
          },
          margin: {
            top: 20,
            bottom: 20,
            left: 20,
            right: 20
          },
          animations: {
            enabled: false
          },
          stacked: true
        },
        xaxis: {
          type: "datetime",
          categories: [],
          tickPlacement: "on"
        },
        yaxis: {
          title: {
            text: "Units"
          },
          min: 0
        },
        grid: {
          show: true,
          borderColor: "#A9A9A9",
          position: "back",
          xaxis: {
            lines: {
              show: true
            }
          },
          yaxis: {
            lines: {
              show: true
            }
          }
        },
        colors: this.getColorsFromData(),
        title: {
          text: "Stacked Area Chart",
          align: "left"
        }, 
        fill: {
          type: "solid",
          opacity: 1
        },
        stroke: {
          show: true,
          width: 1,
          curve: "smooth"
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        legend: {
          position: "bottom",
          formatter: function(val, opts) {
            const color = opts.w.config.colors[opts.seriesIndex];
            return `<div class="legend" style="border-color:${color};">${val}</div>`;
          }
        },
        markers: {
          size: 0
        },
        tooltip: {
          custom: function({ series, seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
            let tooltipText = "<div class='custom-tooltip'>";

            const date = new Date(w.globals.seriesX[0][dataPointIndex]);
            const time = date.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" });
            const formattedDate = date.toDateString() + " " + time;

            tooltipText += `<div>${formattedDate}<br /></div>`;

            series.forEach((seriesItem, index) => {
              const data = w.globals.initialSeries[index].data[dataPointIndex];
              const title = w.config.series[index].name;
              const color = w.config.colors[index];
              tooltipText += `<div><span style='color:${color};'><svg width="12" height="12"><circle cx="6" cy="6" r="5" fill="${color}" /></svg></span> <span style='color:black;'>${title}</span>: ${data.y}kWh</div>`;
            });

            tooltipText += "</div>";

            return tooltipText;
          }
        }
      },
      chartSeries: []
    };
  },
  watch: {
    data: {
      handler(newData) {
        if (newData) {
          this.prepareChartData(); // Call prepareChartData when data is available
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.prepareChartData();
  },
  methods: {
    prepareChartData() {
      if (!this.data) {
        // Data is not available, return and wait for it
        return;
      }

      const seriesData = Object.values(this.data).map(item => ({
        name: item.config.title,
        data: item.data.map(entry => ({
          x: new Date(entry.d),
          y: parseFloat(entry.v)
        }))
      }));

      const categories = Object.values(this.data)[0].data.map(entry => new Date(entry.d).toDateString());

      this.chartOptions.xaxis.categories = categories;
      this.chartSeries = seriesData;
    },
    resetSeries() {
      if (this.$refs.chart) {
        this.$refs.chart.resetSeries(true, true);
      }
    },
    getColorsFromData() {
      const colors = Object.values(data).map(item => item.config.color);
      return colors;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I need the chart to be rendered as a solid color on each stack and not have these vertical lines.

Comment: You might be having `null`s in your data; if that's the case, the simplest solution in your case might be to filter them out, e.g., `data: item.data.filter(({v})=>Number.isFinite(v)).map(entry => ....`.

Comment: if I zoom into those white areas, the white vertical lines are not there. I don't think its an issue with null values.

Comment: Try to make a [reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including the data that results in that problem, possibly in a stackblitz or codesandbox.  I had made a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2hu8p9z/) to test the `null`s hypotesis, with many of the options you listed; you may fork it, if convenient.